# Plural class implementing singular. Is there a name for this design pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Say I have a `Product` interface with a single method `price()`:

```
interface Product {
  fun price(): Float
}
```

Now, I create a `Products` class that implements it:

```
class Products(private val products: List<Product>): Product {
  fun price() : Float {
    return products.fold(0f) { acc, fl -> acc + fl }
  }
}
```

Maybe `Product` is not the best example, but I find this pattern useful when you need to aggregate many products' price in many places of your codebase. This way, that logic is encapsulated in `Products` class.

I wonder if there is a name for this pattern.

Comment: I'm just curious: which programming language is that?

Comment: It's Kotlin. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, this looks like an example of the [Composite design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

---

It looks like you've implemented the composite logic using a fold, which is consistent with the observation that the [Composite design pattern is isomorphic to monoids](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/12/composite-as-a-monoid), and [monoids accumulate](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/11/20/monoids-accumulate). The specific monoid you've used there is the addition monoid.